# Create an unordered map from a vector of structs

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Say I have a class that can easily express key-value semantics:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct data_t{
    T1 m1; 
    T2 m2; 
};
```

What would be the **most efficient way to create an unordered map out of a vector of such structs**?

---

### My approach

I tried to define a *conversion operator* for my class

```
operator std::pair<T1, T2> () { return {m1, m2};  } // typo noted by PasserBy
```

But this doesn't seem to work

```
std::vector<data_t> v; 
std::unordered_map<T1, T2> um(v.begin(), v.end()); // compilation error
```

My particular use case has a pointer type `T1` and a value type `T2` so I suppose there wouldn't be a need to define hash functions (?). Also the reason I'm trying to do it through a conversion operator is to be able to add elements to that unordered map in the same fashion:

```
um.insert(itn, ite); // insert from a range of the source vector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a typo in your conversion operator

```
operator std::pair<T1, T2>() const { return {m1, m2}; }
```

And it should generally be marked `const` too.

The reason for a compile error is that `unordered_map<T1, T2>` holds `std::pair<const T1, T2>`, which your vector doesn't hold.

So this works

```
std::vector<data_t<const T1, T2>> v; 
std::unordered_map<T1, T2> um(v.begin(), v.end());
```

provided that `T1` has a proper hash function.

So does using a different conversion operator

```
operator std::pair<const T1, T2>() const { return {m1, m2}; }
std::vector<data_t<T1, T2>> v; 
std::unordered_map<T1, T2> um(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use transform:

```
unordered_map<int, double> um;
transform(begin(v), end(v), inserter(um, end(um)), [](const auto& data) {
    return make_pair(data.m1, data.m2);
});
```